# How to do transfer learning on a pre-trained ResNet50 with different image size

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, cnn

I have a pretrained ResNet model which is trained on 64x64 images. I would like to do transfer learning with new dataset that contains 128x128 images.

I am loading the model like:

```
    train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_data_dir,
        target_size=(img_size, img_size),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        subset='training') # set as training data

    validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_data_dir, # same directory as training data
        target_size=(img_size, img_size),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        subset='validation') # set as validation data


model = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights=None, input_shape=(64,64,3))
model.load_weights("a trained model weights on 64x64")

model.layers.pop()
for layer in model.layers:
   layer.trainable = False

x = model.output
x = MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='same')(x)
x = Flatten(name='flatten')(x)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
predictions = Dense(101, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(x)

top_model = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=predictions)

top_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
        optimizer=adam,
        metrics=[accuracy])

EPOCHS = 100
BATCH_SIZE = 32
STEPS_PER_EPOCH = 4424 // BATCH_SIZE
VALIDATION_STEPS = 466 // BATCH_SIZE

callbacks = [LearningRateScheduler(schedule=Schedule(EPOCHS, initial_lr=lr_rate)),
                ModelCheckpoint(str(output_dir) + "/weights.{epoch:03d}-{val_loss:.3f}-{val_age_mae:.3f}.hdf5",
                                 monitor="val_age_mae",
                                 verbose=1,
                                 save_best_only=False,
                                 mode="min")
                 ]

hist = top_model.fit_generator(generator=train_set,
                               epochs=EPOCHS,
                               steps_per_epoch = STEPS_PER_EPOCH,
                               validation_data=val_set,
                               validation_steps = VALIDATION_STEPS,
                               verbose=1,
                               callbacks=callbacks)
```

I would like to do transfer learning based with images of 128x128 pixels. I am very new to this, how can I modify?

Is there a way to modify the model input shape? and do I need to do something with spatial size?

And which optimizer is recommended? Adam or SGD?

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res5c_branch2a (Conv2D)         (None, 2, 2, 512)    1049088     activation_46[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn5c_branch2a (BatchNormalizati (None, 2, 2, 512)    2048        res5c_branch2a[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_47 (Activation)      (None, 2, 2, 512)    0           bn5c_branch2a[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res5c_branch2b (Conv2D)         (None, 2, 2, 512)    2359808     activation_47[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn5c_branch2b (BatchNormalizati (None, 2, 2, 512)    2048        res5c_branch2b[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_48 (Activation)      (None, 2, 2, 512)    0           bn5c_branch2b[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
res5c_branch2c (Conv2D)         (None, 2, 2, 2048)   1050624     activation_48[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn5c_branch2c (BatchNormalizati (None, 2, 2, 2048)   8192        res5c_branch2c[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_16 (Add)                    (None, 2, 2, 2048)   0           bn5c_branch2c[0][0]              
                                                                 activation_46[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_49 (Activation)      (None, 2, 2, 2048)   0           add_16[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
pred_age (Dense)                (None, 2, 2, 101)    206848      activation_49[0][0]              
==================================================================================================
Total params: 23,794,560
Trainable params: 23,741,440
Non-trainable params: 53,120
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Getting the following error:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (64, 64, 3) but got array with shape (128, 128, 3)

Answer (score 1):

you did not mention your generator.

Just add target_size to your train_set generator. it can be as follows.

and your dataset should be in "data_generator" folder, with classes as subfolders.

```
train_set =ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)
train_generator= train_set.flow_from_directory('data_generator',
                                                 target_size=(64, 64),
                                                 color_mode='rgb',
                                                 batch_size=32,
                                                 class_mode='categorical',
                                                 shuffle=True)
```

vote up, if this helps ;)

Comment: Ok I forgot to add this and it is similar to yours. Only without  color_mode='rgb', and shuffle=True. My target size is  target_size=(128,128). So if the Resnet model that is trained on weights of (64, 64),  should this work with images with input shape of (128,128)? what about the spatial size? could you explain this?